# Is there any way to trigger v-dialog from vuex store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuex

I have a component just for dialog box and I want to trigger the components v-dialog from specific value on vuex store programmatically . Is there any way to achieve.

Comment: use store value as watcher value on component

Comment: Hi, Thanks! Sorry if I sound stupid. but what will I do for activator ? do you have any example, a codepen or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Make a state and it's getter on which basis you want to trigger dialog box. Add getter in computed properties of component then use it for dialog box.